# Django map exceptions to HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to map an exception to an HttpResponse object in django?

For example, I would like to map my own "UnauthorizedException" to an HttpResponseForbidden response object so when my view raises that exception, rather than automatically getting mapped to a 500, certain exceptions could be treated as 401.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, if you implement your own middleware that implements the [`process_exception`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) method. A quick example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from app.exceptions import UnauthorizedException


class UnauthorizedAccessMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, UnauthorizedException):
           return HttpResponseForbidden("You are not authorized to access that page.")
```